# get_query_set(self) is not being called in django

Tags: django

I am implementing search function using TemplateView in Django the class is

```
class part_search_view(TemplateView):
    model = part_list
    context_object_name = 'part_list'
    template_name = 'part_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(part_search_view,   self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['my_list'] = populate_nav_bar()
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        key = self.request.GET['search_text']
        partlist = part_list.objects.filter(Q(part_id__icontains=key) |      Q(part_name__icontains=key))
        return partlist
```

> part_list.html

```
{% for part in part_list %}

 <a href="{% url 'parts:part_detail' part.id %}" class="list-group-item">{{ part.part_id }} - {{ part.part_name }}</a>
 <a href="{% url 'parts:part_update_view' part.id %}" > Edit </a>

{% endfor %}
```

the url mapping is

```
    url(r'^search/',views.part_search_view.as_view(),name='part_search_view'),
```

the form for serch button

```
    <form action="{% url 'parts:part_search_view'%}" role="form" class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="get" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group ">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search_text">
        <button class="form-control search_buton btn btn-success " type="submit" >Search</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

after the search button is pressed the address is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/parts/search/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=PWjEw1hRsyH9B6YcseVuhS0urX8L7f170q9ucLF9hTPQPThulpgMSP4y5xhScCVr&search_text=mp6
```

but the get_query_set(self) is not called here the get_context_data(...) is called though, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TemplateViews don't know anything about querysets, so they never call a `get_queryset` method. You should subclass a more appropriate view, perhaps ListView.

Comment: can we use listview  URL to have another parameter except than <pk> in URL mapping like I am using <key> here

Comment: Yes of course. You can have any parameters you like in any view you like.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at docs, [TemplateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview) does not have a method `get_queryset()`. Then, you would have to manually call it in the view.